# Get current locale name in perl

Tags: perl, posix, locale

I want to use thousands_sep in Perl. I can get it using the following code

```
use strict;
use POSIX qw(setlocale locale_h LC_ALL);
setlocale(LC_ALL, "fr_FR");
my $lc=localeconv();
print $lc->{thousands_sep};
```

After that I would like to change locale back to previous value, but I don't know how to get locale before I used `setlocale`. Should I parse it from `$ENV{LANG}` which is set to
`en_US.UTF-8` ? Or is there any other method to get locale name?

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perllocale

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`setlocale()` returns the current locale when called without a second argument, eg.

```
my $oldlocale = setlocale(LC_ALL);
```

If you want to set locale according to the current environment, call it with an empty string (ie. `""`).